# Chosen dropdown properties not updated

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I recently change the standard dropdown list to chosen dropdown which include a search box. 
Chosen offers the possibility to define a threshold base on the number of items in the list to disable the search bar.
ex : I don't want a search bar it there are less than 10 items in the list.
The documentation says to use :

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
```

But it doesn't wok for me. Here is my code :

```
<tr class="flavors">
  <td>[brand_list]</td>
  <td>
    <select id="arome0" class="chosen-select"></select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="dropper0" class="chosen-select">
      <option selected="selected" value="type1">type 1</option>
      <option value="type2">type 2-3</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="qtyunit0" class="chosen-select">
      <option value="ml">ml</option>
      <option value="drops">drops</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="perc">%</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input id="quantity0" class="quantity" type="number" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

and my jquery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#marque0").attr('class','chosen-select');
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
        disable_search_threshold: 10,
        no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });
    $(".chosen-select").css("overflow", "initial !important");
});
```

Can you see anything wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({'disable_search_threshold': 10});
```